# 404 image for non existing images [htaccess]

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to show 404 image if the requested image doesnt exist. I got success with this one

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
ErrorDocument 404 "/no.png"
</FilesMatch>
```

However, if user tries to display an image with directory (for ex: example.org/img/nonexistingimage.png), it fails. My question is how to use it with directory ?

Comment: Its working fine on my server. how did it fail for you?